# Is there a workaround for running a step/job upon the cancellation of a build in CircleCI?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, circleci, cicd

After some research on the CircleCI docs, it seems that there is no native way to run a job/command/script/step upon the cancellation of an entire build.

This is a critical issue for my pipelines because I spin up a GCP compute instance in one step of a job and then tear it down in a subsequent step. So if the build is canceled anywhere between these two steps, the compute instance and all of its corresponding infrastructure (VPC networks, firewalls, etc.) do not get deleted.

Has anyone engineered a practical solution to this issue?